# calling up a number converted from a string to an integer

Tags: java

I need help calling up the test numbers so i can use them in the equation above test number i need to use is 013601267

```
System.out.println("Enter the f1rst 9 digit: ");
String v = input.nextLine();

//converts string into an integer
int d = Integer.parseInt(v);

//call up value of d at location 0
int d1 = d.charAt(0);

//print out the value of d1(i'm using this as a test)
System.out.println(" "+d1);


/*
int checksum = (d1*1+ d2*2+ d3*3+ d4*4+ d5*5+ d6*6+ d7*7+ d8*8+ d9*9)%11;

if (checksum == 10)
  System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%dX",d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9);

else 
  System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,checksum);
```

*/

Comment: int d = 013601267 instead of int d = Integer.parseInt(v) ... Not sure exactly what your asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `int d1 = d.charAt(0)`, as `d` is of type `int`, which has no `charAt()` method. If you want a certain digit from number, you can take a `char` from the string and turn it to `int` like this

```
ind d1 = v.charAt(0) - '0';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does the -> - '0'  <- mean on that line? When i typed mine, i did not use that so it gave me the wrong call up so i came here

Comment: It's kind of a helpful little trick, by subtracting the integer value of `0` character (48 in ASCII) from your current character, you effectively transform the character representing a number into the number itself.

Comment: do i have to do this for every number i want to call up?